# Virtualenv hangs on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, pip, virtualenv, easy-install, macos-sierra

Not sure if it's a macOS problem, but I can no longer create virtual environments on my Mac... I tried uninstalling and installing again with `easy_install virtualenv`, but whenever I run `virtualenv test`, my terminal gets stuck at `Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install oh-my-zsh on macOS?
In my experience, when installing oh-my-zsh, it would conflict with virtualenv.
The way to solve the issue is to enable the virtualenv plugin in oh-my-zsh, and remove the setting from ~/.bash_profile.